# AWS Elastic Beanstalk wont load static files from public folder for nodejs app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I have deployed the nodejs application with aws eb deploy, client.js is not getting loaded in index.hbs files and returning 404 error (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found))

I have tried all the step in the internet and wasted two days for this.

Can any one please help me here ? I am doing anything wrong here?

I have tried the solution in this stackover flow page [Elastic Beanstalk Static Folder 403 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490902/elastic-beanstalk-static-folder-403-error) but no luck

**staticfiles.config**(NodejsPlayGround.elasticbeanstalk\staticfiles.config) file

**option_settings:**

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles:
/public: public
```

**index.hbs**(NodejsPlayGround\views\index.hbs) file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>NodeSeverTest</title>
<script src="js/client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**(NodejsPlayGround\server.js) file

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const views_path = path.join(__dirname, 'views');
const static_path = path.join(__dirname, 'public')

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', views_path);

app.get('', (req, res) => {
res.render('index', {
title: 'Weather App',
name: 'ArunKumar Arjunan'
}
);
});
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log('server started on port ' + port);
});
```

**client.js**(NodejsPlayGround\public\js\client.js) file:

```
console.log('client side java script file is loaded');
```

client.js file needs to be loaded in index.hbs file

Answer (score 0):

I find that contrary to the AWS documentation on this, the folder path also needs a leading slash — i.e. you map `/public` to `/public` (not just `public`), or `/static` to `/static` (not just `static`).

I figured this out by inspecting the nginx error log and conf files on my EB instances, and both showed that it was looking for my static files in `/var/app/currentstatic` instead of `/var/app/current/static`.